# Undeclared variables error: code error or wrong installation?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

I have just installed `flex` and I would try to run this simple code:

```
int nLines = 0, nChars=0, nWords = 0;
%option noyywrap
%%
\n        ++nLines; ++nChars;
[^[:space:]]+  ++nWords; nChars += yyleng;
.         ++nChars;
%%
main()
{
    yylex();
   printf("%d lines, %d words, %d characters\n",
             nLines, nWords, nChars);
}
```

but I get: `error: 'Variable_Name' undeclared (first use in this function)` for each variable in the code (`nLines, nChars, nWords`).

I would like to know if it is an issue regarding some error in my code, or if I don't have correctly installed *flex*.

Comment: Where did you copy that code from?

Comment: Don’t you need `%{` before and `%}` after the variable declarations?

Comment: Yes, @JonathanLeffler, he does.

Comment: You can just indent the declaration but using `%{` ... `%}` is probably better style.

Comment: It would also be better to write `int main(void)` rather than the very old-fashioned, not permitted during this millennium notation `main()`.  C90 permitted what you wrote as a concession to pre-standard practice; C99 doesn’t allow it.